# ASP.NET MVC - ValidationSummary with MVC and AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC view that contains a form that I post with AJAX to a controller action then I return a partial view and show it on the same page.

Model A:

```
Public class InputModel
{   
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    public string A { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

View A:

```
@model InputModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions()
{
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
OnSuccess = "Populate(data)"
}))

{
// Validation Summary does not work
@Html.ValidationSummary()
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.A)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.B)
<button id="formSubmission" type="submit"</button>
}

<div id="ResultPartialView"></div>

Function Populate(data)
{
    $('#ResultPartialView').html(data);
}
```

Controller A:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        InputModel inputModel = new InputModel();
        return View(inputModel);
    }

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Index(InputModel inputModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           ResultModel resultModel = new ResultModel();
           resultModel.Id = 5;
           return PartialView("Result", resultModel);
        }

        else 
        {
           Response.StatusCode = 400;
           return PartialView("Errors", inputModel);
        }
    }
```

The issue here is that I cannot show errors in @Html.ValidationSummary() on View A because it is loaded in the DOM before the AJAX call. I tried using OnSuccess and OnFailure to load other partial views with no luck. For example, I tried adding a div to View A

```
<div id="validationSummaryDiv"></div>
```

Then adding this to the the AJAX part:

```
OnFailure = "ShowErrors(data)"
```

Then Creating a new JavaScript function that updates `div id="validationSummaryDiv"`:

```
Function ShowErrors(data)
{
    $('#validationSummaryDiv').html(data);
}
```

Then returning an `"Errors"` view (as showed in Controller A above) that contains:

```
@model InputModel
@Html.ValidationSummary()
```

This did not work. Although I could see the error messages coming back with the HTTP 400 errors in Firefox network but "data" did not contain the partial view. I assume this is because OnFailure does not return data responses.

I'm sure someone had this issue before. In short, what is the best way to return the ModelState errors on View A?

Comment: Please place validation summary inside UpdateTargetId

Comment: Side note: You use of `new { id = "A", type = "text"}` is a bit pointless - the `TextBoxFor()` method already add both of those and you just overwriting them with exactly the same value they already are.

Comment: @mauliksakhare This would be an easy fix but I cannot do that. UpdateTargetId contains a 'second' part of the application that should not get loaded if ModelState is invalid. I need the validation errors to appear above the form.

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. Noted.

Comment: If you attach the debugger, can you step into the PartialView?